# how to disable ALT for showing the shortcut of menu on ubuntu16.04

Tags: shortcuts

How to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcut for showing the first letter of menu?

In some case, I have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Other key</kbd> in `emacs` keymap on Goland IDE.

Comment: for example: 
once i press `alt` + `w`, i expect copy some words, but it popup the Windows menu of GolandIDE.

Comment: At first , i am using `supper ` + `w` ,  but ,you know, i have to configue more settings to disable the `super`

Comment: You will need to configure that in your application. Terminal emulators, for example, include options to disable Alt+key combinations for activiting the menu's.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to modify the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key behavior using `gnome-tweaks`.

For Ubuntu 18.04 and after :

1. Install `gnome-tweaks` and start it:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
   gnome-tweaks
   ```
2. Go to *Keyboard & mouse* -> *Additional Layout Options* (refered as *Options supplémentaires d'agencement* on my screenshot) -> *Alt and Super keys behaviors* (or *Alt and Windows keys behaviors*)
3. Choose the behavior for <kbd>Alt</kbd> key as you want to define it.

[image]

---

If you just want to remove <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts, don't use `gnome-tweaks` as refered before, just modify each shortcuts in *Settings* -> *Keyboard*

[image]